# javascript - know if a link has already been opened

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

I'd like to know if there is a way to know if a link has already been opened. In firefox, the color of a link changes once you clicked it, so I guess it's possible.

Edit : This is for a firefox extension, so **I can't change the HTML or CSS** file.

Thanks :)

Comment: Even though getting this information is allowed by the HTML/CSS standard it is widely regarded in security circles as a privacy violation that you can see your visitors' visited links from other site, so this feature might be disabled in future versions of mainstream web browsers. It might not be a good idea to rely on this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it is possible.

One way is to have different css classes:

```
a:visited { color : red; }
a { color : orange; }
```

Then detect that (in JavaScript).

Comment: Unfortunatly, I can't change the CSS (as I said, it's for a Firefox plugin, and I'm not the owner of the internet :) ).

Comment: gramm: I haven't written a FF plugin but I suspect you can either insert some default/overwriting CSS with it, and/or, apply this to all elements on the page and then check for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the links to have different colours, you can also apply some CSS that will turn out invisible

```
a:visited { padding-left: 1px; margin-left: -1px; }
a { padding-left: 2px; margin-left: -2px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify different colors for unvisited (`:link`) and visited links (`:visited`) and check if the current color of your link has the visited’s one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is possible to see what links were visited. I am saying unfortunately as it is considered a privacy violation. A while ago I came across this blog post [Spyjax – Your browser history is not private!](http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/tools/spyjax/) which describes this.